# Why datafusion HTTP plugin URL macro is not working?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am exploring macros in datafusion pipelines. I am using HTTP Sink plugin and trying to enable macro option for URL option like {URL}. when i try to deploy the pipeline, it is throwing the following error.

Failed to configure pipeline: Stage 'example-pipeline' encountered : URL 'null' is malformed: null

Please help me to resolve this.
Note: Except URL every other option is working as macro in HTTP plugin

Answer (score 3):

Seems like bug in the plugin. Was able to reproduce on my end as well and have filed JIRA https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-16363 for this.

Comment: Can I know what is the ETA for this bug to get fixed ?